# SSH接続をすると、Permission deniedとなり接続できない

Tags: ssh

#### 目標

SSH接続を行う

#### 現状

mac
VPS(Vultr),OSはCentOS

クライアントから、VPSにSSH接続を行ったところ以下のエラーが表示され接続できない。

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

サーバー側の鍵の設定とクライアント側の鍵の設定を変更したが、正しいか分からない。

現状はこうなっています

**クライアント側**

```
-rw-------　id_rsa
-rw-r--r--　id_rsa.pub
```

**サーバー側**

```
-rw------- authorized_keys
-rw------- id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- id_rsa_pub
```

対応方法がわかる方がいましたら回答よろしくお願いします

Comment: サーバー側のsshdのログを確認してください。確認できないのであればVPS提供者に問い合わせるほかないと思います。それとは別に、提示されたファイルはそれぞれどのディレクトリに配置したのでしょうか？ また配置する際に参照された情報の出典を明らかにしてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の手順でたぶん登録できます、試してください。

１、 まずキーを作るので
ssh-keygenコマンドで生成して

2、生成できたid_rsa.pubをサーバー側authorized_keysに追加

```bash
~/.ssh/cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

３、サーバー側に権限をつける

```bash
[root@host .ssh]$ chmod 600 authorized_keys
[root@host .ssh]$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

4、サーバー側の/etc/ssh/sshd_configを編集

```bash
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes #rootで登録必要の場合に使う
```

５、最後にサーバー側ssh再起動

```bash
[root@host .ssh]$ service sshd restart
```

6、クライアント側はid_rsaを持っていれば登録可能です

```bash
~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます
上記のやり方で再度、鍵の生成からやり直してみます！

Answer (score 0):

`id_rsa` は秘密鍵です。一般論として**秘密鍵は生成したマシンから外に持ち出すべきではありません**。つまり、サーバー・クライアント両側に `id_rsa` が存在する時点で、適切な手順ではないことが推測されます。
VPS提供者が提示する手順に従ってファイル配置してください。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます！
秘密鍵がサーバー側にありますので間違えていますね、、
再度鍵の作成からやり直してみます